# Code design and structure

Tags: php

It has recently been highlighted (in my previous questions) that the way I have designed web applications is not ideal.

Consider the following. I am working on a multi-user website with lots of different sections including profiles and forums and support tickets. The structure is as follows:

A main page in which all the other pages are *included* or *required_once* we'll call it **home.php.**

In **home.php**, one of the first things loaded is **router.php**, this handles every single $_GET and $_POST that the user could possibly produce, and every form and process is sorted via a main variable called $data_process.  Router.php is essentially just one giant **switch()** statement for $data_process.  This parses all the data and gives a result.

Next included is **header.php**, which will not only process the neccessary variables for the page that will be loaded but also set up the header and decided exactly what is going to be shown there, e.g. menu, user info, and information about the page currently viewing (i.e. Home > Support > View Ticket).

Then the page is loaded according to $page variable.  A simple include.

Then footer.php, then close.

And so the dynamic website is created.  I was told this is bad practice by a user named @HorusKol.  I am very pleased with this website as it is the most streamlined and easy to write website I have ever used.  If this is still bad code design? What is perfect code design?

PS - can anyone recommend any good easy to read books that explain PHP, MySQL and design structure for me?

Comment: +1 for honest question. If home.php is the starting point for any request, you've got (at least a starting point of) a MVC architecture. Congrats! (and Perfect code design = Untouched theory)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into MVC architecture.

Comment: your `header` is doing a lot of work.... it will be hard to maintain in future if you want some changes in futre.

Comment: There's still a lot of global variables around, which are considered bad practice. Rather than getting a book, download a PHP framework (CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Symfony, Zend) and see how they do it. Do a tutorial if you can find the time - you'll learn a lot.

Comment: I recommand MVC. [Look here to get an idea](http://www.intelliproject.net/articles/showArticle/index/php_mvc_framwork)

Comment: It sounds like a major issue is that router and/or header contain logic for each and every one of your application's pages. This means that the pages are not self-contained (you need to edit two or three places to add one more page) and it makes the router/header very tightly [coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) to the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is bad design because you process a lot of data that is perhaps not necessary in the rest of the process. The router should only process the url, processing of post data is handled somewhere else. Only include what you need, including everything makes things slow.
- A better way is to structure you app more in different parts. A router that is processing the url, a controller that runs a action based on a routed request, a view that processes all html and pages, a model for accessing data. MVC is what comes in mind.
- There is no such thing is the perfect code design.

Comment: But surely the giant `switch` statement only process what is needed to be processed?

Comment: If you process you url like `http://mysite.com/controller/action` you do not need giant switch. Get the controller class form the url and let the controller handle the action.

Answer (score 1):

There's no canonical definition of "good design" - the best you can hope for is that your design balances the various forces on your project in the optimum way, Forces on your project might be maintainability, performance, scalability, extensibility - classic non-functional requirements - but also things like search engine optimization, standards compliance and accessibility (things that apply to web projects in particular).

If all your URLS are of the form "www.mysite.com/home.php?action=getDetails&productID=123", your search engine friendliness is pretty low. It's far better to have semantic URLs - "www.mysite.com/products/DesktopPc/details.php". You can achieve this through cunning .htaccess trickery in your current design.

From a maintainability point of view, your design has some issues. If I've understood it correctly, adding a new page to the site requires you to modify the code in several different source files - router.php (your giant switch statement), the page itself, and probably the header.php as well. That indicates that the code is tightly [coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29). Modifying the giant switch statement sounds like a likely source of entertaining bugs, and the combination of the router and the header, manipulating the variables, plus the actual page itself seems a little fragile. This is okay if you're the only person working on the project, and you're going to be around for the long term; if that's not the case, it's better to use an off-the-shelf framework (MVC is the current favourite; Zend, Symphony and Cake all do this well in PHP) because you can point new developers at the documentation and expect them to get up to speed.

One of the biggest enemies of maintainability is complexity - complex code is harder to work with, and harbours more bugs. There's a [formal metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) for complexity, and I'm pretty sure your switch statement scores very highly on that metric - in itself not necessarily a huge problem, but definitely something to keep an eye on. Lots of MVC frameworks avoid this by having the routing defined as data rather than code (i.e. have the routes in a configuration file), and/or by using convention over configuration (i.e. if the request is for page "productDetails", include the file "/inc/productDetails.inc").

Extensibility could be another concern - imagine having to expose your site content as JSON or XML as well as HTML; in your current design, that would require a lot of change, because every single item in your page processing pipeline cares and needs to know. The home.php needs to know not to send HTML, the header and footer need to know, the router needs to understand how to handle the additional data type, almost certainly making the switch statement even bigger. This again may not be a big deal.

Both extensiblity and maintainability are helped by being able to unit test your code. Test Driven Development turns this into a whole routine in its own right; I'm guessing that testing your application is hard - but that's just a guess; it depends more on how you've factored the individual lumps of code than what you've described above. However, another benefit of MVC is that it makes it easy to write unit tests for key parts of your system.

So, if the forces on your project don't include an emphasis on maintainability or extensibility, and you can handle the SEO aspect, I don't think your design is necessarily "bad"; even if you do care about those things, there are other things you can do to accommodate those forces - write documentation, hire lots of cheap coders.

The best way to get up to speed with these design topics are not books on PHP or MySQL; I'd recommend "Refactoring" and "Patterns of enterprise application architecture" by Martin Fowler, "Design Patterns" by Gamma et al. and Code Complete by McConnell (though that's a touch out of date by now).